# Creating a color preview in AS3 for a drawing application

Tags: actionscript-3, canvas, colors, drawing

i'm quite new to AS3 but I know the basics. I'm creating a drawing application and I would like to create a rectangle that changes to the color selected everytime a new color is selected. I can do the easy stuff such as creating the rectangle etc. but for the actual color transformation I am a bit lost. I haven't found a direct answer with this and I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Flash Professional has a color picker component; it'd be helpful to understand if you're using Flash Pro or building pure ActionScript projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program that creates a red button on the stage. When clicked, it changes to blue.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var ButtonA:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
ButtonA.buttonMode = true;

ButtonA.graphics.lineStyle(1,0);
ButtonA.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000,1)
ButtonA.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);

addChild(ButtonA);
ButtonA.x = ButtonA.y = 20;

ButtonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColorHandler, false, 0, true);
function changeColorHandler(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
    var obj_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    obj_color.color = 0x0000ff;
    ButtonA.transform.colorTransform = obj_color;
}
```

This uses a click event, but you can take the code inside the handler and create your own color setter function that you can call from wherever you want. i.e:

```
function changeColor(obj:MovieClip, newColor:int) : void
{
    var obj_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    obj_color.color = newColor;
    obj.transform.colorTransform = obj_color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of rectangle when new color is selected , i think  you should use color picker control from flash Professional ,please import color picker control and attach to you project

```
           function ColorPicker_Class()
    {
                   colorPicker=new ColorPicker();
        addChild(colorPicker);
        colorPicker.x=150;
        colorPicker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,onChangeColor);

                    rect=new Sprite();
         rect.x=300; rect.y=250;
         addChild(rect);
           }
         function onChangeColor(event:ColorPickerEvent):void
    {
        var colorpick:ColorPicker=ColorPicker(event.currentTarget);
        rect.graphics.lineStyle(1);
        rect.graphics.beginFill(colorpick.selectedColor,1);
        rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
    }
```